# Dismiss a ShortcutViewController after setting it

Tags: ios, swift, ios12, sirishortcuts

I Implements SiriShortcut with Intent in my App.

I set up a button "Add to Siri" with the code that Apple give here : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/inuiaddvoiceshortcutviewcontroller

```
 func addSiriButton(to view: UIView) {
    let button = INUIAddVoiceShortcutButton(style: .blackOutline)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    view.addSubview(button)
    view.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    view.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addToSiri(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
}

// Present the Add Shortcut view controller after the
// user taps the "Add to Siri" button.
@objc
func addToSiri(_ sender: Any) {
    if let shortcut = INShortcut(intent: ProjectorOnIntent()) {
        let viewController = INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewController(shortcut: shortcut)
        viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
        viewController.delegate = self as? INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewControllerDelegate // Object conforming to `INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewControllerDelegate`.
        present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

But once I record a phrase when I click on the "Ok" button the view won't dismiss.

The error I got in the console :

```
2018-10-12 10:16:51.985156+0200 AppName[1029:172350] [default] No results found for query: {(
<_LSApplicationIsInstalledQuery: 0x28226e560>
)}
2018-10-12 10:16:51.989467+0200 AppName[1029:172263] [strings] ERROR: Add to Siri not found in 
table Localizable of bundle CFBundle 0x111a01d00 </var/containers/Bundle/Application/DDADF244-FBCE-47C0-90F8-E8C8ADA6962E/AppName.app> (executable, loaded)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hope it help you,

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewControllerDelegate, INUIEditVoiceShortcutViewControllerDelegate {
    func editVoiceShortcutViewController(_ controller: INUIEditVoiceShortcutViewController, didUpdate voiceShortcut: INVoiceShortcut?, error: Error?) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

     func editVoiceShortcutViewController(_ controller: INUIEditVoiceShortcutViewController, didDeleteVoiceShortcutWithIdentifier deletedVoiceShortcutIdentifier: UUID) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func editVoiceShortcutViewControllerDidCancel(_ controller: INUIEditVoiceShortcutViewController) {
         controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func addVoiceShortcutViewController(_ controller: INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewController, didFinishWith voiceShortcut: INVoiceShortcut?, error: Error?) {
         controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func addVoiceShortcutViewControllerDidCancel(_ controller: INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewController) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }    
}
```

Use INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewControllerDelegate and INUIEditVoiceShortcutViewControllerDelegate

Thank you.